# Split and map array from comma separated string list in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dictionary, angularjs-filter

I want to merge two lists that are comma separated, `CENTURY, BADGER` & `65, 85` to form an array like: `[{name: 'CENTURY', price: '65'}, {name: 'BADGER', price: 85}]`, the lists are in an json object:

```
{
    unit: '35 lb',
    brands: 'CENTURY, BADGER'
    prices: '65, 85'
}
```

So what I've done is a filter:

```
angular
    .module( 'app.purchases.products' )
    .filter( 'mergeDetails', mergeDetails );

function mergeDetails() {
    return function ( product ) {
        _.merge( product.brands, product.prices );//Using lodash, any suggestion?
        console.log('brands ', product.brands);
        return product.brands;//`_.merge` will add prices to brands
    }
}
```

I'd like to know how to apply the filter to an interpolation `{{ }}` so that I could get the array and use it in a `ng-repeat`, here's where it is used:

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in products">
    <td>{{product.unit}}</td>
    <td>
        <!-- Here I should filter to ng-repeat the resulting array -->
        {{product.brands +' '+ product.prices}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 5):

I think if you look for output like this `CENTURY, BADGER, EXO` you just need to do so

```
  <li ng-repeat="p in products">
    <p>{{p.brands}}</p>
  </li>
```

I edit this to add filter could help 
add this filter

```
 .filter('customSplit', function() {
  return function(input) {
    console.log(input);
    var ar = input.split(','); // this will make string an array 
    return ar;
  };
});
```

And your HTML view modified to

```
   <li ng-repeat="p in products">
    <p ng-repeat="brand in (p.brands | customSplit)">{{ brand }}{{$last ? '' : ', '}}</p>
  </li>
```

Comment: You misunderstood what I said, I want the opposite of that... I have the string like `CENTURY, BADGER, EXO`

Comment: you maybe need a to make filter split it

Comment: Why use a filter? Why not simply use `brand in p.brands.split(',')`?

Comment: `brand in p.brands.split(',')` is nice, I missed this one

Comment: I updated the question for a better understanding, check it out

Answer (score 3):

[Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is helpful when transforming arrays.

If you have a single of your starting "product", you can make it into an array like this:

```
var expandedProduct = product.brands.split(',').map(function(brand, index) {
  return {
    'name': product.name,
    'brand': brand.trim(),
    'cost': product.costs.split(',')[index].trim(),
    'vat_cost': product.vat_costs.split(',')[index].trim()
  }
});
```

You could build on that to transform an array of them.

Answer (score 0):

this should do it:

```
var transpose = function(obj){
    var result =[];
    for(key in obj){
        var aux = obj[key].split(",");
        for(i in aux){
            if(result[i]==null){
                result[i]={};
            }
            result[i][key]=aux[i].trim()
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don't prefer filters as a solution for this problem, because as the term defines, its should be used for filtering/selecting the items to display. As [Steve Campbell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34445408/2770248) suggests, you should transform/map the products into your desired form. [Demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/2BZ2DTios0jbNniEnncS/)

```
// flatten the pr0ducts into one array ...
vm._products = data.reduce(function (previous, current) {
                        return previous.concat(generateMergeList(current))
                    }, []);

// helper function to generate a list of product in a product data object
function generateMergeList(source) {
var result = [];
if (!source || !source.brands || !source.prices) {
    return result;
}

var _brands = source.brands.split(',');
var _prices = source.prices.split(',');

if (_brands.length !== _prices.length) {
    throw 'Number of items in brands and prices aren\'t the same...';
}

return _brands.map(function (elm, idx) {
    return {
        brand : elm,
        price : _prices[idx],
        unit : source.unit
    };
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arrayDefaultDeliveryDay = Array.from(this.defaultDeliveryDays.split(","));
let arrayDefaultDeliveryFoodType = Array.from(this.defaultDeliveryFoodType.split(","));
let arrayDefaultDeliveryStartTime = Array.from(this.defaultDeliveryStartTime.split(","));
let arrayDefaultDeliveryEndTime = Array.from(this.defaultDeliveryEndTime.split(","));

var deliveryDetails = [];

for(var i = 0; i<=arrayDefaultDeliveryDay.length-1; i++){
  deliveryDetails.push({
    foodType : arrayDefaultDeliveryFoodType[i],
    day : arrayDefaultDeliveryDay[i],
    startTime : arrayDefaultDeliveryStartTime[i],
    endTime : arrayDefaultDeliveryEndTime[i]
  })
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(deliveryDetails));
```

After a lot of research, Finally found the solution.

Comment: That `Array.from` is redundant, `split` returns an array. You can also replace `i<=arrayDefaultDeliveryDay.length-1` with `i<arrayDefaultDeliveryDay.length` or even read `arrayDefaultDeliveryDay.length` before `for` loop and use `i<someVariable`